# Creating a new variable using many column

Tags: r, loops, variables, if-statement

I am trying to create a new variable by combining 25 other variables (different time points during the night). Here are five of the time points, for example:

```
   net_8pm net_830pm net_9pm net_930pm net_10pm net_1030pm
1       0         0       0         1        1          1
2       0         0       0         0        0          0
3       0         0       0         0        0          0
4       0         0       1         1        1          1
5       1         0       0         0        0          0
6       0         1       1         1        1          1
```

In my data, they're columns 34:58. If they used a net last night, the value=1, if they did not, the value=0. There are some missing data points, coded "NA". I want to make newvar=1 if ANY of time points=1, and 0 if they NEVER=1.

I tried a big long ifelse string, which is ugly and doesn't seem to pick up all of the rows (I have 182 people, and I only get 160 when I run the ifelse string). I'm terrible with making my own functions and loops, so everything I have tried has been a bust. I either get the dreaded  - about 90% of the things I try:

```
for (i in colnames(df)[38:54]){
+ df$net_ever<- ifelse(i==1, 1, 
+ ifelse(i==0, 0,
+ NA))
+ }
> table(df$net_ever)
< table of extent 0 >
```

Or it turns into 4450 rows:

```
collapse_ifelse<-function(x){
+ ifelse(x==1, "yes", 
+ ifelse(x==0, "no",
+ NA))
+ }
> df$net_ever<-apply(df, 2, FUN=collapse_ifelse)
```

or I get this warning:

```
> f1<-function(x){
+ for (i in 1:x)
+ ifelse(x==1, "yes", 
+ ifelse(x==0, "no",
+ NA))
+ }
> df$net_ever<-apply(df, 2, FUN=f1)
There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In 1:x : numerical expression has 182 elements: only the first used
```

Or I get 182 0's:

```
> df$net_ever2<-rep(0,182)
> for (i in 1:182){
+ ifelse(i==1, "yes", 
+ ifelse(i==0, "no",
+ NA))
+ }
> table(df$net_ever)

  0 
182
```

You can see I have no idea what I'm doing here (it is embarrassing enough having to post these for help, but desperate times call for desperate measures). I'd greatly appreciate help with how to collapse these variables! I'm using R 3.0.3 with Windows 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `any` by row:

```
df$net_ever <- apply(df[38:54], 1, any)
```

Comment: You could add the argument `na.rm=T` just to make sure the resulting vector will have no NAs.